# MPLAB gives Low power and device failed to connect error when programming pic18f25q10

Tags: c, pic, mplab, pic18, mplab-c18

I am trying to add a simple led application to a PIC18F25Q10 in another circuit using the Curiosity HPC development board. I am using the MCLR, PGD, PGC and GND pins. Although I set the LVP mode to enable in the CONFIG settings and the program speed to low in the project properties, MPLAB " MPLAB has detected that the undervoltage configuration bit on the device is off and you have selected" error output . I also cannot connect to the PIC.
My MPLAB version is 6.5
I am using the X8 compiler (2.40).
I am throwing code with PKoB4.

1. I checked my circuit connections and confirmed that the MCLR, PGC and PGD pins were correct, but I kept getting errors.
2. I have done the steps to be applied here, but I have not reached a result. I cannot connect to the PIC.

```
Connecting to MPLAB PKoB4

Currently loaded versions:
Application version...........00.05.79
Boot version..................01.01.41
Script version................00.05.35
Script build number...........86fedc5c2e
Tool pack version ............1.8.869
Target voltage detected

MPLAB has detected that the low voltage configuration bit on the device is off and you have selected the low voltage programming option on the debug tool's property page. If you wish to use the low voltage programming option you must first do the following:
* Turn off the low voltage programming option on the debug tool's Program Options property page
* Program the low voltage configuration bit to on
* Turn on the low voltage programming option on the debug tool's Program Options property page
Connection Failed.
```

3. I checked the forum pages and updated MPLAB and the PKoB4 drivers to test the information that it might be version related, but I could not connect to the PIC.
4. I used another circuit because I thought there would be a problem with the PIC. I got the same error. I tried to load the code from another computer and I continued to get the same error.
5. I tried to code with ICD, it codes. However, I could not solve this error on the Curiosity HPC development board. I came across some information in the Curiostiy development board user's guide.
   [information Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgwJz.png).

I need to be able to connect to the PIC and throw code. I am curious about your thoughts and advice about my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the advise of MPLAB your PIC chip has programmed to have LVP disabled. The curiosity boards has a built-in PICKIT which can program only in Low Voltage Programming mode. So you have to do the following steps:

1. Get a standalone PIC (i.e. PICKIT3) programmer
2. In config settings of your PIC set the LVP to be on
3. In MPLAB IDE, **File** > **Project Properties** > **PICkit 3** > **Program Options** make sure that *Use low voltage programming mode entry* option is unchecked
4. Burn your PIC device with this configuration once using the standalone PICKIT programmer

These steps will prepare your PIC so that it can be programmed in curiosity board. Once you done with all steps correctly, you will be able to burn your programs using your curiosity.
When you program with the built-in programmers, you always wanna make sure that your PIC is programmed before with configuration `LVP = ON`. And also keep this config bit always `ON` as long as you keep programming it in a curiosity board.
One more thing to tell, MPLABX is automatically checks the *Use low voltage programming mode entry* option when you select the *Connected Hardware Tool* as your curiosity board.
Go ahead and try the steps and then let me know if I could help any further.